# Css no opacity on inside div when image is on body

Tags: html, css

My code is like this

```
<body style="background: url('im.jpeg')">
<div class="inner" style="opacity:0.5;margin-left:20px">
  <div class="innermost">
  <p>My content</p>
  </div>
</div>   
</body>
```

The problem with my code is that it body has an image so that it would be on full screen and class "innermost" has original content including pics and texts , opacity is assigned to "inner" class. And this opacity affects all element of "innermost".
Is there any solution to prevent opacity of "innermost" class without affecting body style.
Thanks for reading.

**Update**

is there any other alternative of my code , such that i can have image on full screen.

Comment: it is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/ADY4f/

Comment: See that question, it will tell you the answer (which is sorry, it won't work) and it will give you some workarounds (none of which are great).

Comment: might be, so what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a parent element has an opacity value set at, say, 0.5, all of its children will inherit that opacity setting, and there’s no way to reverse that opacity on the child elements.
Read this http://www.impressivewebs.com/fixing-parent-child-opacity/

Comment: not exactly but it seems good.I'll try to implement it.Thanks

Comment: in that example the author has used js.. and im not the real author of the site

Answer (score 2):

It is not going to happen the way you want. If innermost is inside inner, it is part of its content, and will be transparent too.
Depending on what you want to achieve, you can apply an alternative. For example, a transparent background. Or remove innermost from inner, and use position absolute:

```
<div style="position:relative;margin-left:20px">
    <div class="inner" style="opacity:0.5;">

    </div>
    <div class="innermost" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
        <p>My content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: srry im not satisfied

Comment: And why is that? What else are you after?

Comment: as I mentioned I want image to be displayed

Comment: I see. You want a code that you can copy, paste and magically see working. Sorry, can't provide you satisfaction.

Comment: dude I respect your thoughts , but I really don't mean that, I just wanna know , there must be some previous example and u need not to be so rude

Comment: @rickj Hugo Silva is right, transparent PNG is the way to go. Even if it doesn't satisfy you. :)

Comment: @domdev , so how can we use image in that

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to add css property "style: none" for your class "innermost". Doing that, you "stop" the opacity specified below.

Comment: no dude opacity doesn't relate to style